# captureOutput from AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate is not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avcapturesession, avcapturevideodataoutput

I am seeking to leverage the device camera as a light sensor as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921326/how-to-get-light-value-from-avfoundation/46842115#46842115). Unfortunately, the `captureObject` function is never called by the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. It may be relevant that I am attempting this inside of a SwiftUI app, I have not seen this problem posted about or resolved in the context of a SwiftUI app.

```
class VideoStream: NSObject, ObservableObject, 
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    @Published var luminosityReading : Double = 0.0
    
    var session : AVCaptureSession!
        
    override init() {
        super.init()
        authorizeCapture()
    }

    func authorizeCapture() {
        // request camera permissions and call beginCapture()
        ...
    }

    func beginCapture() {
        print("beginCapture entered") // prints
        session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()
        let videoDevice = bestDevice() // func def omitted for readability
        print("Device: \(videoDevice)") // prints a valid device
        guard
            let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice),
            session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)
        else {
            print("Camera selection failed")
            return
        }
        
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        guard
            session.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        else {
            print("Error creating video output")
            return
        }
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: 
             "VideoQueue"))
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        session.sessionPreset = .medium
        session.commitConfiguration()
        session.startRunning()
     }

    // From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921326/how-to-get-light-value-from- 
       avfoundation/46842115#46842115
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, 
        from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        print("captureOutput entered")  // never printed
        
        // Retrieving EXIF data of camara frame buffer
        let rawMetadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(allocator: nil, target: sampleBuffer, attachmentMode: CMAttachmentMode(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate))
        let metadata = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, rawMetadata) as NSMutableDictionary
        let exifData = metadata.value(forKey: "{Exif}") as? NSMutableDictionary
        
        let FNumber : Double = exifData?["FNumber"] as! Double
        let ExposureTime : Double = exifData?["ExposureTime"] as! Double
        let ISOSpeedRatingsArray = exifData!["ISOSpeedRatings"] as? NSArray
        let ISOSpeedRatings : Double = ISOSpeedRatingsArray![0] as! Double
        let CalibrationConstant : Double = 50
        
        //Calculating the luminosity
        let luminosity : Double = (CalibrationConstant * FNumber * FNumber ) / ( ExposureTime * ISOSpeedRatings )
        luminosityReading = luminosity
    }
}
```

Lastly, I instantiate `VideoStream` as a `StatreObject` in my `ContentView` and attempt to read the updated `luminosityReading`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(format: "%.2f Lux", videoStream.luminosityReading))
            .padding()
    }
}
```

I have read and implemented the solutions described in these similar posts:

[Using AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate without a preview window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663309/using-avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate-without-a-preview-window)

[captureOutput not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999250/captureoutput-not-being-called)

[captureOutput not being called from delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773336/captureoutput-not-being-called-from-delegate)

[captureOutput not being called by AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573039/captureoutput-not-being-called-by-avcaptureaudiodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate)

[In Swift, adapted AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, but captureOutput never getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097642/in-swift-adapted-avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate-but-captureoutpu)

[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput captureOutput not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890791/avcapturevideodataoutput-captureoutput-not-being-called)

[Swift - captureOutput is not being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835264/swift-captureoutput-is-not-being-executed)

[Why AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate method is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742909/why-avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate-method-is-not-called)

[Why captureOutput is never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70301935/why-captureoutput-is-never-called)

[func captureOutput is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324851/func-captureoutput-is-never-called)

[captureOutput() function is never called swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650493/captureoutput-function-is-never-called-swift4)

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(format: "%.2f Lux", videoStream.luminosityReading))
    }
}

class VideoStream: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    @Published var luminosityReading : Double = 0.0
    
    var session : AVCaptureSession!
        
    override init() {
        super.init()
        authorizeCapture()
    }

    func authorizeCapture() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
            beginCapture()
        case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
                if granted {
                    self.beginCapture()
                }
            }
            
        case .denied: // The user has previously denied access.
            return
            
        case .restricted: // The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
            return
        }
    }

    func beginCapture() {
        
        print("beginCapture entered")
        
        let testDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        print("Image Capture Device: \(testDevice)")
        guard
            let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: testDevice!),
            session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)
        else {
            print("Camera selection failed")
            return
        }
        
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        guard
            session.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        else {
            print("Error creating video output")
            return
        }
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "VideoQueue"))
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        
        session.sessionPreset = .medium
        session.commitConfiguration()
        session.startRunning()
    }
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        print("captureOutput entered")  // never printed
        
        // light meter logic to update luminosityReading
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: It should be included in the question, links break over time and people with the same issue wouldn't have access to the full picture

Comment: I understand, I will edit my question now

Comment: It is an issue of copy and paste... you are missing one very simple step/line. What is the purpose/intention behind those `guard`? That is likely why this question has been marked as duplicate before

Comment: The `guard` statements ensure that the input and output can be added to the `AVCaptureSession`, but of course you realize this, I am scratching my head trying to figure out the significance they have to my problem and what I might be missing...

Comment: `session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)`

Comment: Yup.... That is the right spot

Comment: Wow, I am not sure how long it would have taken me to spot that... a valuable lesson learned about copying and pasting from Apple Docs.  If you would like to submit an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I started rewriting the issue using `async await` and was actually displaying the session on my screen. It was blank so I started debugging from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing adding the input

```
if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput){
    session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
}
```